# How to add await in a for loop to wait for function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

im a beginner in Javascript / Nodejs.

i want to read a folder, and then each by each call a function with await...

I have a Folder, inside that folder i have Images.
with readdir i get all Folder Images with extension.

with that code i read the folder and split the ImageName and the .png, so i have only the ImageName without the .png.

idk if there is a better solution.

```
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
   const split = file.split('.');
   .....split[0]
  });
});
```

If i add then this code inside the readdir

```
storeAsset();
```

Code from storeAsset

```
async function storeAsset() {
   const client = new NFTStorage({ token: NFT_STORAGE_API_KEY })
   const metadata = await client.store({
       name: 'ExampleNFT',
       description: 'My ExampleNFT is an awesome artwork!',
       image: new File(
           [await fs.promises.readFile('assets/Test.png')],
           'MyExampleNFT.png',
           { type: 'image/png' }
       ),
   })
   console.log("Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with URL:", metadata.url)
}
```

The Function storeAsset() run without Problem but its not waiting to finish StoreAsset and then each by each.

If i Add await that the forEach loop wait for finish each File...;

```
await storeAsset();
```

i get this Message:

```
await storeAsset();
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
←[90m    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:115:18)←[39m
←[90m    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:289:14)←[39m
←[90m    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21)←[39m
```

So, how i can modify the readdir function with await storeasset that every function call wait for finish and then the next one?

thanks for helping

edit:

i have this now:

```
    fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(async file => {
   const split = file.split('.');
//
    await storeAsset();
//
   console.log(split[0]);
    //   process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

but its a bit wrong...

```
Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with URL: ipfs://xxx/metadata.json
4
Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with URL: ipfs://xxx/metadata.json
5
Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with URL: ipfs://xxx/metadata.json
1
Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with URL: ipfs://xxx/metadata.json
3
Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with URL: ipfs://xxx/metadata.json
2
```

I need: 1 Image > Upload wait for Return Answer, then 2 Image and so on, and not start every upload at same time and then the upload is mixxed and not 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: what node version are you using? `node -v`

Comment: await must be used in functions declared with `async` only.

Comment: @tbjgolden v16.14.2

Comment: @Peterrabbit Any example with my code Sir?

Comment: Do you need to wait for one file to finish before processing the next one, or do you just have to wait until all of them are finished (in any order)?
Also, arrow functions can be declared to be async like in `files.forEach(async file => {})`

Comment: @qrsngky I must wait each file for Uploading > Returned Hash and then the next one. files.forEach(async file => {}) this working, but its not each by each file the upload

Comment: @qrsngky i edited my first post, its not working correctly

Comment: @Peliguglu I posted an example that should stick to your case. But I'm not sure I fully got the way your implementation is going.. So it might need to be adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic example to show how asynchronous code can be used along with readdir and a loop

```js
const fs = require("fs")

function pr(f) {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("got file " + f)
        }, 500)
    })
}

const pth = __dirname; // whatever directory path with something in it...

fs.readdir(pth, async (err, files) => {
    // Don't use a forEach syntax as it doesn't support asynchronous code, 
    // it would not throw an error, but the promises won't be 
    // resolved inside the loop with forEach.
    for (const f of files) { 
        const msg = await pr(f);
        console.log(msg)
    }
})
```

And here is an example that should correspond to your case (it didn't not fully understand where you call the store asset and how you use the files iterator but it should illustrate the point)

```js
fs.readdir(testFolder, async (err, files) => {
    // ...
    for (const file in files) {
        await storeAsset();
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This is it, thank you very much! Learned now how this works with async! Now its each by each with wait for the first one :) Nice!

Answer (score 1):

For iterations to wait for the previous one, and the previous one is running something async, you can wait for it using a simple for loop and await.

Array methods like forEach do not have a mechanism to allow them to wait for an async operation to finish before moving onto the next iteration.

Finally, the reason you are getting the `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` is that the forEach function must be an async function, though that won't solve the problem you're trying to here.

```js
const run = async () => {
  for (const x of list) {
    await do(x)
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: If i use your example and add again the await storeAsset.... i get the same error... seems i do anything wrong :/